# Как правильно вызвать функцию и отрисовать её содержимое в условии цикла без привязки к итерациям?

Tags: javascript, валидация

Всем привет, имеется код в котором прописана небольшая валидация на проверку пустых select. Проверка работает правильно, по клику на кнопку get если хотя бы 1 select пустой, то функция render() не отрабатывает. В данном случае, когда render() отрабатывает, то выводится 2   console.log() скорее всего из-за количества итераций select. Можно ли как то избежать данного поведения? У меня в проекте, условно в функции render(), рендерится карточка и на данный момент выводится две карточки по клику на кнопку get, хотя мне нужна одна. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот код

на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acqogd2f/2/)

или:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent")
const error = document.querySelector('.error')
const select = document.querySelectorAll('.select')
const card = document.querySelector('.card')

//клик на get
parent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("remove")) {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
    return
  }
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('button')) return
  let parentBlock = e.target.closest('.parent')
  let childBlock = parentBlock.querySelectorAll('.select')
  let ok = true
  childBlock.forEach((opt) => {
    let option = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex];
    if (option.disabled) {
      opt.classList.add("input-error");
      ok = false
    } else if ([...document.querySelectorAll('.select')].every(x => x.value)) {
      opt.classList.remove("input-error");
      render() //должно выводиться в соответствии с количеством узлов child, а не итераций по select
    } else {
      card.innerHTML = ''
    }
  });
  error.innerHTML = ok ? "" : 'Выберите информацию из выпадающих списков'

  function render() {
    console.log('render')
  }
})


//клик на add select
const child = document.querySelector(".child")
const add = document.querySelector(".add")

add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  child.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterend",
    `<div class="child">
                <select class="select">
               <option value="" disabled selected>List</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <select class="select">
               <option value="" disabled selected>List</option>
               <option value="5">5</option>
               <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>
        <span class="remove">X</span>
        </div>`
  );
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <select class="select">
      <option value="" selected disabled>List</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select">
      <option value="" selected disabled>List</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button class="button">get</button>
    <div class="error"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add">add select</button>
<div class="info"></div>

<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: Не вызывай `render()` в цикле. В цикле узнай, нужно его вызывать или нет и уже после цикла делай выводы по вызову `render()`.

Comment: C `else if ([...document.querySelectorAll('.select')].every(x => x.value))` ты совсем намутил... Полная ерунда.

Comment: А как обычно определяют признак того, нужно вызывать функцию или нет? Да и после цикла можно вызвать функцию по условию в зависимости от количества узлов?

Comment: Для создания ответа нужно понять твой сценарий для скрипта. Есть 2 селекта. Есть кнопка которая может добавить еще пару селектов и так до бесконечности. Что должна делать кнопка `get`?

Comment: Да, селекты можно добавлять без ограничений по количеству по клику на add select, а по клику на get в проекте у меня рендерятся карточки, в каждой из которых отрисовывается текст из селектов по принципу блока child, информация с одного child выводится в 1 карточке. Если пользователь с помощью add select создал еще несколько блоков с селектами и выбрал все option, то выведется несколько карточек с текстовой информацией из option по принципу: первая карточка(1 2), вторая карточка(1 1) например. Но повторюсь что в цикле данные очевидно дублируются и будет 4 карточки вместо 2.

Comment: Пока я понял только что по `get` что-то будет делаться... Но ты еще там что-то проверяешь. Я тебе давал уже ответ как проверить и потом что-то делать. Но ты опять все засунул в цикл и еще добавил одну и ту же проверку на каждую итерацию. Туда же добавил и `render()`. Все эти "последние доделки" не правильные.

Comment: Ну вот я 2 комментария оставил и по вашему ответу я примерно так теоретически понял что нужно делать. https://jsfiddle.net/9am0ojeL/

Comment: Всё таки я намудрил у себя в голове, ваш первый комментарий мне помог: "Не вызывай render() в цикле. В цикле узнай, нужно его вызывать или нет и уже после цикла делай выводы по вызову render()". Всё проще чем думал, спасибо. Еще один вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста по поводу этой строчки: ```else if ([...document.querySelectorAll('.select')].every(x => x.value))``` хочу убрать эту халтуру, как более правильно можно проверить option у select на disabled?

Comment: К самой проверке претензий нет. Но не в цикле же ее запускать. Она ведь каждую итерацию делает одно и тоже. Эту проверку можно запустить один раз и "до" цикла. И потом решать что делать с результатом этой проверки.

Comment: Аа вы в этом плане, это я на скорую руку набросал, так то да проверку как минимум надо присвоить к переменной и уже работать с ней.

Comment: Уже будет прогресс! :)